# вычитание в питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

проблема с вычитанием в питон:

```
5 - 4.23  # выводит 0.7699999999999996
```

хотя

```
5 - 3.23 # 1.77 работает нормально
```

В чем проблема? Знаю что возникают ошибки с делением на float но тут вычитание да еще и такое простое

Comment: [`0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

можно так, но вообще это числа с плавающей точкой так работают

```
a = 5 - 4.23
a = round(a, 2)
print(a)
```

или использовать Decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal('5') - Decimal('4.23'))
```